# How to load an Ember Component in application template before everything else?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, leaflet

I’m currently building a little Ember App that allows users to access a newspaper’s travel tip articles through a map. Therefor I’ve build a little Leaflet component that displays a map the app can interact with (animate to coordinates, change zoom and stuff).

The map is the central element of the app and is always visible. So I placed the component into the application template. It fills the whole background and is positioned fixed. All child routes are rendered in `div.content` that “hovers” over the map.

```
…
<div class="app-body">
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application" id="application">
  <div class="map-container">
  {{leaflet-map
        id="map"
        class="map"}}
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
  </script>
</div>
…
```

As I have to preload all the articles with their coordinates right at the beginning (to place all markers), I added the preloading to the beforeModel hook of IndexRoute and fetch the data from store in the routes’ model hook via `return this.store.all('article');`.

The idea is that the map in the background loads right at the beginning and is already visible when the app starts to preload the articles. I thought that would be the case if it is placed into the application template directly. Obviously it’s not. The map is loaded and displayed *after* the preloading is completed and I don’t have a clue how to change that. Would be great if someone could hint me in the right direction.

**Update**
The console logs show that the compontent, despite it’s part of the application template, is initialized at the end after everything else. No idea why.

```
…
[✓] template:index ............................................. template at index
[ ] view:default ............................................... undefined.DefaultView
Transition #0: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
[ ] helper:leaflet-map ......................................... undefined.LeafletMapHelper
[ ] component-lookup:main ...................................... undefined.MainComponentLookup
[✓] template:components/leaflet-map ............................ template at components/leaflet-map
[✓] component:leaflet-map ...................................... undefined.LeafletMapComponent
```

Comment: Why split things up into `beforeModel` and `model` here? Seems to me you can get rid of your code in `beforeModel`, and then simply have the `model` hook be `return this.store.find('article')`.

Comment: It’s not that simple. The API I have to work with forces me to loop through several pages of articles to get them all. So–instead of implementing this into the adapter–I did a separate recursive preloading function that returns a promise that resolves into the next call returning its promise and so on. In the end all articles get pushed to the store. To keep things tidy, I separated the preloading and put it in the beforeModel hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template (map) won't be rendered until the model resolves. The model won't be resolved if either hook `beforeModel` or `afterModel` return promises.

You placed the map in the application template and fetch articles from the index route, good. The problem is that nested routes, that return promises, block their parents too. The application transition is blocked until the index transition resolves.

So while you wait, you can use [Loading / Error Substates](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) . In this case, the loading state.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sihedi/1/edit?html,js,output

With the loading state you allow a partial rendering and when the nested route completes its transition, the loading template is replaced with whatever your app does.

Comment: That’s exactly what I did. As you can see in my code snippet the component is placed within the application template. The articles are then preloaded and fetched from index route.

Comment: Right, I improved the answer and provided an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you load your app, the first thing it's going to do is handle the `App.ApplicationRoute`. It will go through its model hooks, set up the controller, and render the template. After that, it will do the same for the `App.IndexRoute` (note: an index route is always implicitly created underneath parent routes), and render its template into the `{{outlet}}` you have defined above.

Thus, It seems to me that you should put the code that finds your markers into into `App.IndexRoute`.

You may still have an issue, however. If your `{{leaflet-map}}` component is something that must be loaded asynchronously (which seems to be the case looking at http://leafletjs.com/reference.html), the map itself won't appear instantly after the component is rendered in the DOM. In this case, you should listen for the event that says the map has been loaded, and then trigger an action that can be handled at the route layer to load the markers.

Comment: Yes, articles (and therefor markers) are loaded from IndexRoute. I had the same thought regarding the map being loaded async. As I load about 140 articles from IndexRoute it takes a little while and the map appears right _after_ the preloading is done. So it doesn’t seem to be a problem of the map taking too long to be loaded.